# How to sort object of angular material table

Tags: angular

I have the following dataSource which has following structure

```
0: {isGroupBy: 'Anchorage'}
1: {isGroupBy: 'Berth 2'}
2: {createByUserId: null, updatedByUserId: null, createdDateTime: '2021-11-16T13:46:50.47012Z', updatedDateTime: '2021-11-22T20:42:10.72Z', id: 102072, …}
3: {createByUserId: null, updatedByUserId: null, createdDateTime: '2021-11-16T13:52:36.835646Z', updatedDateTime: '2021-11-22T20:45:46.729Z', id: 102093, …}
4: {isGroupBy: 'Berth 1'}
5: {createByUserId: null, updatedByUserId: null, createdDateTime: '2021-11-16T13:12:43.
```

I want to sort according to isGroupBy property
How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mat-sort-header in your html code. Add it to  tag. Like this:

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      Is Group By
    </th>
```

Then add these codes to your ts code:

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

and

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

And that's it.

Also it's a good idea to see this page from Angular material documentation:
https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Comment: I don't have header for isGroupBy Key, my html is something like this  <ng-container matColumnDef="groupHeader">
      <td colspan="999" mat-cell *matCellDef="let groupBy"><strong>{{groupBy.isGroupBy}}</strong></td>
    </ng-container>

Comment: My only way is to sort, this in .ts file using sort method or something, I did try but nothing works for me

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/sort-overview-example.ts